# Duplicates in Django QuerySet when using annotate + filter + annotate

Tags: django, django-models, duplicates, django-queryset

I'd like to annotate a queryset based on both all related objects and filtered subset. Let's say we have some books and they are sold at some stores at some prices. Now, for one book, I'd like to get all the stores which sell that book, the price of the book in those stores and the average price of books in each of those stores.

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, through='BookInStore')


class BookInStore(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('book', 'store')
```

Create some objects:

```
book1 = Book.objects.create(title='book1')
book2 = Book.objects.create(title='book2')
book3 = Book.objects.create(title='book3')
store = Store.objects.create(name='store')
BookInStore.objects.create(book=book1, store=store, price=10)
BookInStore.objects.create(book=book2, store=store, price=100)
BookInStore.objects.create(book=book3, store=store, price=1000)
```

Now, for book1, I'm trying filter the stores that sell book1, get the prices in those stores and also the average price of all books in each of the stores:

```
book_availability = (
    Store.objects
    .annotate(avg_price=Avg('bookinstore__price'))
    .filter(bookinstore__book=book1)
    .annotate(
        duplicates=Count('bookinstore__price'),
        book_price=Sum('bookinstore__price')
    )
)
```

However, it doesn't work correctly:

```
for b in book_availability:
    print("Avg price:", b.avg_price)
    print("Number of copies (should be 1):", b.duplicates)
    print("Price of book1 (should be 10):", b.book_price)
```

I get the following output:

```
Avg price: 370.0
Number of copies (should be 1): 3
Price of book1 (should be 10): 30
```

The average price is correct. But for some reason, the price of the book has been multiplied by the number of total books in the store. What am I doing wrong? How should I get the kind of queryset I'm after?

Comment: Have you tried to add `distinct()` to the queryset to remove duplicates just in case there are any?

Comment: Not supported by my backend (sqlite) I think: "NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend"

Comment: I'm not asking you to do `distinct()` on individual fields, but just do `distinct()` on the queryset. It's equal to `SELECT DISTINCT` in sql: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, putting `distinct()` at any possible position, didn't help, so I thought I'd need to do it based on an individual field.

Comment: Even putting `distinct()` at all the positions didn't change the result: `book_availability = Store.objects.distinct().annotate(avg_price=Avg('bookinstore__price')).distinct().filter(bookinstore__book=book1).distinct().annotate(book_price=Sum('bookinstore__price')).distinct()`

Answer (score 0):

One workaround: Because book&store combinations are unique, it shouldn't matter whether one uses `Sum`, `Avg`, `Min`, `Max` or something similar for getting the price of the particular book, because there should be only one item. However, using `Sum` sums the weird duplicates, so it is better to use `Min` or `Max` to get the correct integer because they give the correct answer in the presence of duplicates:

```
book_availability = (
    Store.objects
    .annotate(avg_price=Avg('bookinstore__price'))
    .filter(bookinstore__book=book1)
    .annotate(
        duplicates=Count('bookinstore__price'),
        book_price=Min('bookinstore__price')
    )
)
```

And printing now:

```
for b in book_availability:
    print("Avg price:", b.avg_price)
    print("Number of copies (should be 1):", b.duplicates)
    print("Price of book1 (should be 10):", b.book_price)
```

We see the correct book price now:

```
Avg price: 370.0
Number of copies (should be 1): 3
Price of book1 (should be 10): 10
```

This workaround happens to give the correct answer but it doesn't remove the duplicates, so I'm still wondering if there is something wrong in the approach.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `Case` and `When` to do the filtering for the annotation:

```
book_availability = (
    Store.objects
    .annotate(
        avg_price=Avg('bookinstore__price'),
        book_price=Sum(Case(When(
            bookinstore__book=book1,
            then='bookinstore__price'
        )))
    )
    .filter(bookinstore__book=book1)
)

for b in book_availability:
    print("Avg price:", b.avg_price)
    print("Price of book1 (should be 10):", b.book_price)
```

Which gives:

```
Avg price: 370.0
Price of book1 (should be 10): 10
```